# How to configure htaccess file for Cake 2.3.x on 1and1 shared hosting

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, cakephp, mod-rewrite

Using the default cakephp htaccess file setup will not work on my domain when I want to install my Cakephp app in a subfolder, while everything works on localhost (xampp)

target => http://example.com/mycakeapp

Install needs 3 htaccess files:

root .htaccess

```
#.htaccess in root
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteBase  /mycakeapp
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

In app .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteBase /mycakeap
   RewriteRule    ^$   app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*)  app/ webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

In webroot .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On 
    RewriteBase /mycakeapp
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Following CakePHP's documentation, and Using these htaccess files, I get error500 results.
Using RewriteBase / instead of /mycakeapp will throw 404 error page.

PHP is in 5.4 version. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setup your rules like this:

**.htaccess in DOCUMENT_ROOT**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule (.*) mycakeapp/$1 [L]
```

**.htaccess in DOCUMENT_ROOT/mycakeapp**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /mycakeapp/
RewriteRule (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
```

**.htaccess in DOCUMENT_ROOT/mycakeapp/app**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /mycakeapp/app/
RewriteRule (.*) webroot/$1 [L]
```

**.htaccess in DOCUMENT_ROOT/mycakeapp/app/webroot**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /mycakeapp/app/webroot/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: Hi and thank you for your help. Now I can see my app. However this setup redirects mydomain.com/mycakeapp to mydomain.com as if my cakeapp was install in root folder. Actually, I do not need this redirection. How can I change this ?

Answer (score 7):

**/dirCakePhp**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^$ /app/webroot/ [L]
    RewriteRule (.*) /app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

**/direCakePhp/app**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^$ /webroot/ [L]
    RewriteRule (.*) /webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

**/direCakePhp/app/webroot**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Juste add '/' after RewriteRule,

And change PHP version in 1and1 hosting panel to => 5.2
Add date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Paris'); in core.php