# 1and1 subdirectory cakePHP installation issue

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp

I am deploying my app on a live server hosted on 1and1.co.uk.

I am trying to make it work since 8 and getting crazy, trying with a fresh version downloaded from the `cakePHP` website.

Here is my configuration.

A subdomain pointing to a directory :

```
subdomain.mydomain.com => /subdirectory
```

So I think the first question is, on the view of my app, is that a subdirectory ?

I don't think so but I am not sure.

I tried hundreds of `.htaccess` configurations, nothing works, I get a 500 error or the following message:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting '(' in /homepages/41/d201409564/htdocs/hire/lib/Cake/bootstrap.php on line 173

I thought [that topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20441896/how-to-configure-htaccess-file-for-cake-2-3-x-on-1and1-shared-hosting) would fix my problem, but still not working.

Thanks for your help

Comment: seems you're getting a php error and not a .htaccess one. Something seems to be wrong in bootstrap.php file. This is strange because this is a cakephp file you don't have to modify. Did you modify it? What cakephp version are you using? And what php version?

Comment: No it's definitely not a PHP error. It's an untouched core file coming from a fresh install.
I am using CakePHP 2.4.4 Stable and PHP 5.5

Comment: just for my curiosity: what do you have in bootstrap.php at line 173?

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20441896/how-to-configure-htaccess-file-for-cake-2-3-x-on-1and1-shared-hosting/20972839#20972839][1]



  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20441896/how-to-configure-htaccess-file-for-cake-2-3-x-on-1and1-shared-hosting/20972839#20972839

Comment: I already put this link in my topic saying it didn't fix my problem.
The solution is bellow for 1and1 shared hosts
enforce php5 + "Options +FollowSymLinks"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could fix it finally thanks to : http://www.grafikart.fr/forum/topic/2351

Here is the solution, the trick is probably to enforce the PHP5, even if it's activated on your server (which is my case)

**/.htaccess**

```
AddType x-mapp-php5 .php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

**/app/.htaccess**

```
AddType x-mapp-php5 .php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule    ^$ webroot/    [L]
RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

**/app/webroot/.htaccess**

```
AddType x-mapp-php5 .php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Wroked for me I have install cake on 1and1 server and site was on sub domain.

Comment: this is working code for my.1and1.com hosting ..thanks

Answer (score 2):

If someone struggles about this with CakePHP 4.xx, this is how i got it running at IONOS (former 1and1). CakePHP is installed in a Subdirectory:

- (Maindirectory)

  - Subdirectory (CakePHP)

**/.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    #the next two lines are only for forwarding to https
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_Port} !=443
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://yourdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
    # end of forwarding

    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^(\.well-known/.*)$ $1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^$ webroot/ [L]
    RewriteRule (.*) webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

**webroot/.htaccess:**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```