# CakePHP htaccess files on 1und1 webserver

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I'm trying to install my cakephp webapp on an 1und1 (German version of 1and1) webspace.
PHP and MySQL are installed and there seems to be a problem with my htaccess files as I can't open the css files for example on the webspace (404).

How does my .htaccess files have to look like?

The application is not installed in the root directory (that's unfortunately not possible), it's located under:

```
http://www.mysite.de/myfolder/system
http://www.mysite.de/myfolder/system/app
http://www.mysite.de/myfolder/system/app/webroot
```

I tried a lot of combinations. But none are working.
The last example I tried were the answers from this question: [how to configure htaccess file for Cake 2.3.x on 1and1 shared hosting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20441896/how-to-configure-htaccess-file-for-cake-2-3-x-on-1and1-shared-hosting)

Any recommondations?

Comment: copy a fresh .htaccess file from cakephp folder and replace it in your project htaccess.It may solve your problem,But am not 100% sure.

Comment: This was the first thing I tried. Didn't work ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the built in method for url-rewriting solved my problem: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/configuration.html#core-configuration-baseurl